# Pop up message when there are no records

Tags: django, alert

template

```
{% for item in category %}
   <tr>
       <td>{{ item.Invoice_No }}</td>
       <td>{{item.Invoice_Date_Of_Issue}}</td>
       <td>{{ item.PO_No }}</td>
       <td>{{ item.Estimate_No}}</td>
       <td>{{ item.Customer_Id}}</td>
       <td>{{ item.Subject_Id}}</td>    
       <td>{{ item.Discount}}</td>
       <td>{{ item.Status }}</td>
       <td><a name="del" href='/invoiceupdate/{{item.Invoice_No}}/'>Update</a></td>
      <td><a class="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure to delete this item?" href='/invoicedelete/{{item.Invoice_No}}/'><img src="http://icons.iconseeker.com/png/fullsize/aspnet/trash-delete.png"></a></td>


   </tr>
   {% endfor %}
```

view.py

```
def Invoice_date(request):
    id = Invoice.objects.all().values_list('Customer_Id', flat=True)       
    note=request.POST.get("fromdate")
    note1=request.POST.get("todate")
    if request.method=="GET":
        form=InvoiceForm
    else:
        category=Invoice.objects.filter(Invoice_Date_Of_Issue__range=[note,note1])
        return render_to_response('test.html',locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    return render_to_response('test.html',locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I want to display a pop up message when there are no records in the Invoice within selected date range.

Can Someone please help me out in doing this??Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you are already filtering your object according to the date in your view, you can do it in your template:

```
{% if category %} 
    dor your for
{%else%}
    call your javascript or show a message
{%endif%}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
{% if category %}
    {% for item in category %}
       <tr>
           <td>{{ item.Invoice_No }}</td>
           <td>{{item.Invoice_Date_Of_Issue}}</td>
           <td>{{ item.PO_No }}</td>
           <td>{{ item.Estimate_No}}</td>
           <td>{{ item.Customer_Id}}</td>
           <td>{{ item.Subject_Id}}</td>    
           <td>{{ item.Discount}}</td>
           <td>{{ item.Status }}</td>
           <td><a name="del" href='/invoiceupdate/{{item.Invoice_No}}/'>Update</a></td>
          <td><a class="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure to delete this item?" href='/invoicedelete/{{item.Invoice_No}}/'><img src="http://icons.iconseeker.com/png/fullsize/aspnet/trash-delete.png"></a></td>

   </tr>
{% empty %}
 <p>You have no records available</p>
   {% endfor %}


 {% else %}
    <p>No category records available</p>
{% endif %}
```

and in your view.py
 initially send categorey value as None

```
categorey = None

def Invoice_date(request):
    category = None
    id = Invoice.objects.all().values_list('Customer_Id', flat=True)       
    note=request.POST.get("fromdate")
    note1=request.POST.get("todate")
    if request.method=="GET":
        form=InvoiceForm
    else:
        category=Invoice.objects.filter(Invoice_Date_Of_Issue__range=[note,note1])
        return render_to_response('test.html',locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    return render_to_response('test.html',locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers. But i still have some problem. I was calling the template 2 times. In the second attempt i am passing category value. First time when template gets called Category doesn't have any value and so i was getting the error even before i pass values

Comment: Thankyou somuch Gaurav